# Data type "Array" in "User.repositories" is not supported by "mysql" database

Tags: javascript, mysql, typescript, typeorm

I have two entities with using typeorm like below:

```
user.entity

  @Column({array: true})
  @OneToMany(() => Repository, repo => repo.user)
  repositories: Repository[];

repository.entity

  @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.repositories)
  user: User;
```

why when i launch my app, from my mysql throw me an error:

```
Data type "Array" in "User.repositories" is not supported by "mysql" database
```

i try to add   `@Column({array: true})` but without success, i drop all db but it still not work

Answer (score 0):

```
@Column("text", {
    array: true
})
repositories: Repository[];
```

That fix your problem but make sure you really need `array` field in `OneToMany` relation.

```
@OneToMany(() => Repository, repo => repo.user)
repositories: Repository[];
```

I guess that's all you need. See [Many-to-one / one-to-many relations](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations.md)

Comment: yes, because my user need to have more than one repository object, i'm wrong?

Comment: Yeap, I think you're missing some concepts of one-to-many relationship. For example: User have photos: @OneToMany(() => Photo, photo => photo.user) photos: Photo[] mean, your photo table have user_id and thats enough. You don't need @Column() here. See [docs](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations.md)